# Connect to Android emulator from android studio dev env. in a Virtualbox vm

Tags: android-studio, networking, android-emulator, adb

I'm trying to setup my Android/ iOS development environment. My setup includes the following:

- A MacOS VirtualBox VM with Android studio and Xcode. The VM is running on a Windows desktop. The network for the VM is currently set up as bridge adaptor.
- A Windows laptop with Android SDK and emulator.

All of the above machines are on the same LAN and I can ping one machine from another and vice-versa.

```
VM with Android Studio - 192.168.1.84
Laptop with emulator - 192.168.1.75
Emulator is running on the laptop on default port - 5554
Emulator IP address in the settings is showing as - 192.168.232.2
```

After reading the [emulator networking guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking), I tried setup the following redirection

```
redir add tcp:5000:5555
```

Subsequently, I tried connecting to the emulator from the MacOS VM by running the following command:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.75:5000
```

The above command resulted in:

```
failed to connect: '192.168.1.75:5000' - Operation timed out error
```

Could you please advise what I'm missing here. I need to set this up as I'm unable to run the Android emulator on the MacOS VM due to other constraints.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

Further to above, I tried to use the following command on the laptop running the emulator to do the redirection:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5000 connectport=5555 connectaddress=192.168.232.2
```

Interestingly, now when I try to run the following adb command from VM containing Android studio, I get the following message -

```
adb connect 192.168.1.75:5000 
already connected to 192.168.1.75:5000
```

However, the emulator (on windows laptop) name does not show up as a device in Android studio (on MacOS VM) and I cannot run my sample application.

Am I missing anything basic here?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that does not requires any port redirection is the following:

On your laptop

1. Start the emulator
2. Use `adb -a nodaemon server` that restarts the `adb` listening on all the network interfaces

On your VM

1. Connect to the remote emulator instance by using this command `adb -H 192.168.1.75 -P 5037 shell` (or instead of `shell` any other commands)

Tested on Mac laptop and Linux VM.

Comment: Thank you @Lino for the answer. I tried the same steps and I was able to connect to the shell. However, `adb connect 192.168.1.75:5000` still throws the same error. In any case now, how do I make that emulator (running on windows laptop) available as device in the Android studio (running on MacOS vm) to run my sample application from Android Studio? Is it possible to issue some commands in shell that would allow me to do this? Apologies, I'm pretty new the mobile development space...

Comment: Hope you are well. I was wondering if you had any thoughts regarding my response. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to analyze Android Studio source code but I didn't understand how to provide custom adb params... (and if this scenario is included)